# what does the "u" mean in "jdku" in java development kit?

Tags: java, adoptopenjdk

I am seeing it in some download files e.g. `OpenJDK21U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_2023-08-09-06-56.tar.gz`?

Some of the github brances are also suffixed with "U".

Comment: Where exactly do you see such a download file?

Comment: [*Update*](https://www.java.com/releases/). And I think that's a [beta](https://github.com/adoptium/temurin21-binaries/releases).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means "update"

Based on the [release guide for OpenJDK](https://github.com/adoptium/temurin-build/blob/master/RELEASING.md):

> When the repository has been created, a few changes to the codebase will be necessary where the code references a jdk version but not it's new update version. I.e. jdk11 became jdk11u when it was moved to an update repository.